Passing state variables from client components before initial render using Next.Js
I have an application in Next.Js where I have a dashboard that I want to populate with data from other pages. My problem is that I cannot find a good way to save variables and then pass them to the dashboard if the other pages have not been loaded yet. For instance I want my dashboard to show the total number of entries I have in my table on my tables page. I can get that information to populate by using zustand and context provider wrappers but I can only achieve this after I have visited the tables page and the data populates.
I have tried using zustand stores and context providers to wrap my application in and they only work once the client side component containing the data has been rendered.
